# How to handle foreign key assoication in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have two models joined through a `foreign_key` attribute which they both share.

```
# app/models/building.rb
belongs_to :building_basic_info, primary_key: "name", foreign_key:"name"

# app/models/building_basic_info.rb
has_many :buildings, primary_key: "name", foreign_key:"name"
```

I'm trying to write a Factory that will create both a `building` and a `building_basic_info` and associate them through the attribute `name`.

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :building do
    name "cannon"
    factory :building_with_bbi do
       name "cannon"
    end
  end
end

building = build_stubbed(:building)
building.building_basic_info
# => nil... but I want it to return the associated building_basic_info object
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :building do
    name "cannon"
    association :building_basic_info
  end

  factory :building_basic_info do
    name "cannon"
  end
end
```